# How can I import COM .tlb file into C++ file with relative path?

Tags: c++, import, com, unmanaged

I have a COM .tlb file and I want to import into my c++ project without using the absolute path of the tlb file. How can I do this?

I'm using Visual Studio and there are some C# and C++ projects. One of my C# project register COM object and generates .tlb file. After that I want to use this file with another C++ project. So I tried to import it. With absolute path (.tlb file location is my solution output directory) works properly (1) and I can also use relative path (2), but what I want to use for import is (3). The main reason for this is very simple I want to avoid to use Debug or Release path in my code. I found a solution for this (4), but when I try to build my solution (e.g in Release mode) then it also wants to read the Debug file and I think this is not the best solution (First of all I have to build my COM C# project in Debug and Release and after that I will be able to build my entire solution). So my question is that, Which C++ project option has effect to the #import? I tried to set VC++ Directories -> Library Directories to $(SolutionDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\ but it didn't work. Thank you for your help in advance!

(1)
    #import "C:\MyProjects\Project\x64\Release\myfile.tlb
or 
    #import "C:\MyProjects\Project\x64\Debug\myfile.tlb

(2)
    #import "..\x64\Release\myfile.tlb"
or
    #import "..\x64\Debug\myfile.tlb"

(3)
    #import "myfile.tlb"

(4)
    #ifdef RELEASE
    #import "..\x64\Release\myfile.tlb"
    #else
    #import "..\x64\Debug\myfile.tlb"
    #endif

When I try to use #import "myfile.tlb" with the following option:
VC++ Directories -> Library Directories to $(SolutionDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\

Comment: Usually, tlb files are the same no matter if the build is debug or release (they are simply declarations)

Comment: (3) should have worked just fine.  You'd better check what that C# project is doing, it does not by default save the .tlb file to the solution directory.

Comment: Use procmon from sysinternals to check what paths Visual Studio uses exactly (you can filter on file events only and on process name for example)

Comment: "Usually, tlb files are the same no matter if the build is debug or release"
Exactly, I didn't know this.
My solution for this issue: I use postbuild action which copy the .tlb file from the output directory to another place e.g: "C:\MyProjects\Project\Source\myfile.tlb" with xcopy. And now I can use easily this: #import "myfile.tlb"

Thank you for your answers, in my special case this solution was the best for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the path of this  .tlb file ("C:\MyProjects\Project\x64\Release\myfile.tlb")
 is NOT added to '$(SolutionDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\' .

Please, check that the value of '$(SolutionDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\' and add the path of your .tlb file to it hence helping Visual Studio to find the .tlb file.
OR maybe copy the .tlb file to one of the directories which is already in  '$(SolutionDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\'

Another suggestion : Also check if the .tlb is correctly registered.

hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I used "#import" in VStudio2019 directive. In order to fix the issue I applied the next:

- I have selected the option "All Configurations" in Configuration from the combo list
- I included the path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ado" to Configuration Properties->VC++ Directories->Library Directories.
  (This path may be change, please verify where are the tlb files)